# Why my app breaks when building it with eas?

Tags: firebase, react-native, environment-variables, expo

I just finished this app, when i run it whit expo start, it all seems to work fine, nothing crashes and everything looks great, but when i build the app with eas build or eas build --profile=x the app builds into an apk, it finish without errors, but when i install the apk and run the app i only see a white screen, and i don't know what is happening.

Here is my eas.json:

```json
{
    "cli": {
      "version": ">= 0.44.0"
    },
    "build": {
      "development": {
        "developmentClient": true,
        "distribution": "internal",
        "android": {
          "buildType": "apk"
        },
        "env": {
          "APIKEY": "",
          "AUTHDOMAIN": "",
          "PROJECTID": "",
          "STORAGEBUCKET": "",
          "MESSAGINGSENDERID": "",
          "APPID": "",
          "MEASUREMENTID": ""
        }
      },
      "preview": {
        "distribution": "internal",
        "android": {
          "buildType": "apk"
        },
        "env": {
          "APIKEY": "",
          "AUTHDOMAIN": "",
          "PROJECTID": "",
          "STORAGEBUCKET": "",
          "MESSAGINGSENDERID": "",
          "APPID": "",
          "MEASUREMENTID": ""
        }
      },
      "production": {
        "android": {
          "buildType": "apk"
        },
        "env": {
          "APIKEY": "",
          "AUTHDOMAIN": "",
          "PROJECTID": "",
          "STORAGEBUCKET": "",
          "MESSAGINGSENDERID": "",
          "APPID": "",
          "MEASUREMENTID": ""
        }
      }
    },
    "submit": {
      "production": {}
    }
  }
```

I'm also using firebase so i'm using those environment variables, i have a .env file and also this on the eas.json file, my hypotesis is that maybe the firebaseApp is not initializing but i think the app is supposed to crash then, doesn't it? The app doesn't close when this happens it only appears a white screen with nothing in it.

Here is the repository of the project:
https://github.com/david1opez/MercadoTec

Comment: reply https://docs.expo.dev/classic/building-standalone-apps/

Comment: can you try `adb logcat` to see if there's a run-time issues

Answer (score 3):

What works for me is using a doting file (https://docs.expo.dev/guides/environment-variables/)

1. Create a .env file with your firebase keys:

```
API_KEY=YourApiKey,
AUTH_DOMAIN=your-auth.domain.com
...
```

2. Install babel-plugin-inline-dotenv. This will load your.env file (https://github.com/brysgo/babel-plugin-inline-dotenv)
3. Your firebaseConfig should look like this:

```
firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
  ...
}
```

4. Your Babel config should look like this:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
 api.cache(true);
 return {
   presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
   plugins: ['inline-dotenv'],
 };
};
```

5. Your eas.json should look like this:

```
{
  "cli": {...}
  "build": {
    "development": {...},
    "preview": {...},
    "production": {
      "env": {
        "API_KEY":"YourApiKey",
        ...
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {...}
  }
}
```

Comment: did this work? also what do you mean "What works for me is using a doting file" - did you also have the same issue - a blank screen after building a production app? I am facing that issue EAS online build gives a blank screen and a dead app. EAS local build submitted through eas submit on the command line works when I then create a release in play.google.com Playstore portal. When I install this local version from The Playstore it works but not the cloud built version installed from the Playstore also! Not sure why the cloud build doesn't work and the local build does??